# Need help Creating Table from query results

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble creating a table from my query results.
I have this code:

```
// Model
<?php
    class Search_Employee extends CI_Model {
        function getAll() {
            $searchterm = $this->name = $_POST['empname'];

            $this->db->like('first_name', $searchterm);
            $this->db->or_like('last_name', $searchterm); 

            $q = $this->db->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, deparment.name FROM employee
                                   INNER JOIN deparment ON employee.department_id = department.id
                                   WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR last_name LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%'");

            if ($q = $this->db->get('employee'))
            {
                if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                    foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                        $data[] = $row;
                    }
                    return $data;
                } else {
                    echo "No results found.";
                    return array();
                }
            } else {
                echo sprintf("DB Query Failed: %s", $q);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
// Controller
class Employees extends CI_Controller {
    function search_employee()
    {
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->model('search_employee');

        $data['main_content'] = 'display_employee';
        $data['rows'] = $this->search_employee->getAll();

        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    }

}
```

---

```
// View
<h1>Results</h1>
<?php
$this->table->set_heading('Name', 'Last Name', 'Department');
$tmp = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">' );
$this->table->set_template($tmp);

foreach ($rows as $r) :
    $this->table->add_row($r); ?>
endforeach;
?>
```

I keep getting a

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\employees\application\views\display_employee.php on line 15
Line 15
```

is the `foreach()` loop.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the query returning results?  Could be that an error has occurred and false is returned from your getAll function.

Comment: I would also like to add that your query leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: yes, the query is returning results.

Comment: how could i prevent sql injection attacks on that query?

Comment: Use prepared statements.  i know doctrine uses them, and I think DB_DataObject does (but db data object is super old and a pain in the butt,s o I don't recommend it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what class `$this->db` object is referring to and it seems nor mysql nor mysqli or PDO. By the way it seems like `$this->db->get('employee')` is not returning an object.

Maybe you committed a typo and you meant `$this->db->result()` which could be a function that returns your last query's result.

You could also check (`if (is_object($q)) {}`) if `$q` is object before treating it like it.

Why don't you replace

```
foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

with `$data = $q->result;`?

If you want further informations you better add some code regarding this DB class, then I'll update my answer.

References:

- [is_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php)

Comment: im refering to codeigniters db class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

Comment: @ebecker, why are you selecting results (first query) into `$q` to replace them with `if ($q = $this->db->get('employee'))`?